# PDOException: could not find driver in WAMP

Tags: php, pdo, wamp

I am getting the error:

> PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp64\www\populate.php:19
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\populate.php(19):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=r...', 'Username', 'Password') #1
>   {main}

When running my PHP code (Below is line 19) from my local WAMP server.

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$server_name;Database=$database_name;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $key);
```

I have checked the php.ini file as described in other similar questions and below is a snippit of that modified php.ini file

```
extension=mysqli
extension=odbc
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

The PHP version I am using is 7.2.25
Below is a snippet of the phpinfo() file regarding the loaded PDO files
[image: PDO DRIVERS]

What do I need to change to get this working?
Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are 2 `php.ini` files in WAMPServer. Use the wampmanager menus to access the one that controls PHP under Apache. `wampmanager->php->php extensions->(make sure pdo_mysql is Ticked)`

Comment: Are you trying to access SQLServer by any chance

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 php.ini files in WAMPServer. Use the wampmanager menus to access the one that controls PHP under Apache.

```
wampmanager->php->php extensions->(make sure pdo_mysql is Ticked)
```

ALL the extension you have loaded.... for PHP5.4 and PHP5.5 and PHP5.6 are completely irrelevant to PHP7.2 which you claim you are running

Also all extensions (DLL's) must be Thread Safe to run in WAMPServer, so only install the `ts` versions and definitely NOT the `_nts_` versions

Comment: How do I determine if a .DLL is a `ts` version and not `_nts_`?

Comment: They have `_TS_` Is Thread Safe and `_NTS_` is Non Thread Safe like I saif in the answer

Comment: Thanks, I removed them as they are for older PHP versions. I have completed the actions in your answer but still get the same error. The `php.ini` file for apache is named `phpForApache` is this the file you were referring to? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Yes and No. Do it via the menu links. It does not actually edit that `pgpForApache.ini` file directly. When you use the MENUS it makes sure you edit the correct file

Comment: Did you install the SQLServer extension that ARE relevant to PHP7.2??

Comment: yes I have but still get the same error `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7x_ts.dll` and
`extension=php_sqlsrv_7x_ts.dll`. I access the php.ini file from the wampmanager menus (`php-> php.ini`)

Comment: Is there really a `1` after `.dll` ?

Comment: That was a typo from formatting to code in StackOverflow - Removed now